# Why memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have tried `LeakSanitizer` in `clang` at the first time. I add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=leak -g")` into my `CMakeLists.txt`.

here is my `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_queue.h"

int main() {
    linked::Char_queue charQueue;
    charQueue.enqueue('1');
    charQueue.enqueue('2');
    charQueue.enqueue('3');
    charQueue.enqueue('4');
    charQueue.enqueue('5');
    charQueue.enqueue('6');
    charQueue.enqueue('7');
    charQueue.enqueue('8');
    while (!charQueue.empty()) {
        char temp = charQueue.dequeue();
        std::cout << temp << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And `linked_queue.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_LINKED_QUEUE_H
#define TEST_LINKED_QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class linked_queue {
public:
    linked_queue() : head(Node()), tail(&head) {}

    ~linked_queue() {
        Node *cur = head.next; 
        while (cur) {
            Node *prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
            delete prev;
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const { return head.next == nullptr; }

    T dequeue() {
        T ret = head.next->data;
        head.next = head.next->next;
        return ret;
    }

    void enqueue(const T &x) {
        tail->next = new Node(x);
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    [[maybe_unused]] [[nodiscard]] bool full() const { return false; }

private:
    struct Node {
        Node *next;
        T data;

        explicit Node(const T &data = NULL) : next(nullptr), data(data) {}
    };

    Node head;   
    Node *tail;  
};

namespace linked {
    using Char_queue = linked_queue<char>;
}

#endif //TEST_LINKED_QUEUE_H
```

When I run this, I got a feedback:

```
=================================================================
==14617==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e48c in main main.cpp:21
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e4f0 in main main.cpp:26
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e4dc in main main.cpp:25
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e4c8 in main main.cpp:24
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e4b4 in main main.cpp:23
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e4a0 in main main.cpp:22
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e504 in main main.cpp:27
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x100a62778 in wrap__Znwm+0x48 (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x6778)
    #1 0x10068e778 in linked_queue<char>::enqueue(char const&) linked_queue.h:33
    #2 0x10068e518 in main main.cpp:28
    #3 0x1836f1f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64+0x16f30)

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 128 byte(s) leaked in 8 allocation(s).
```

It seems like `tail->next = new Node(x);` caused the leak, but I believe that there should not be a leak actually. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Because bug in queue. Have to deallocate memory aquired with new. Why believe not should leak then? Elaborate plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `enqueue` calls `new` and `dequeue` doesn't call `delete`, if you `enqueue` and then `dequeue`, you will leak.

Comment: thanks, I just check ~linked_queue many times ......It is a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works until you never use `dequeue` :D. When you call dequeue, you have no pointer at your dequeued Node and then this Node causes the memory leak. You must delete this Node in your function `dequeue` or you save a pointer to this node and delete it in the destructor. I would prefer the first approach, because you don't need the dequeued nodes anyways.